# How to improve the XML validator to recognize a correct XML String?

Tags: java, xml

I have this regex based `XML` validator that I would like to use for recognizing 
XML string. Say, I have the following `XML` String,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<molecules>
  <molecule id="1">
    <atoms>
      <atom id="1" symbol="C"/>
      <atom id="2" symbol="C"/>
      <atom id="3" symbol="N"/>
    </atoms>
    <bonds>
      <bond atomAId="1" atomBId="2" id="1" order="SINGLE"/>
      <bond atomAId="2" atomBId="3" id="2" order="DOUBLE"/>
    </bonds>
  </molecule>
</molecules>
```

I use the following validator for the `XML`,

```
public static boolean isValidXML(String inXMLStr) {

        boolean retBool = false;
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;

        // REGULAR EXPRESSION TO SEE IF IT AT LEAST STARTS AND ENDS
        // WITH THE SAME ELEMENT
        final String XML_PATTERN_STR = "<(\\S+?)(.*?)>(.*?)</\\1>";

        // IF WE HAVE A STRING
        if (inXMLStr != null && inXMLStr.trim().length() > 0) {

            // IF WE EVEN RESEMBLE XML
            if (inXMLStr.trim().startsWith("<")) {

                pattern = Pattern.compile(XML_PATTERN_STR,
                        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);

                // RETURN TRUE IF IT HAS PASSED BOTH TESTS
                matcher = pattern.matcher(inXMLStr);
                retBool = matcher.matches();
            }
            // ELSE WE ARE FALSE
        }

        return retBool;
    }
```

However, the methods returns `false` even for the valid `XML` as well. How do I correct the `isValidXML` method?

Comment: You have provided a sample XML but there are so many variations that could happen in XML that it is difficult to get what you want with regular expressions.  Will all your input XMLs be tags with no content in them?  The hardest part is what do you want to do when tags come inside of a tag because your regular expression shows that you want to validate tag endings.  More advanced XML validation can be done with SAX Parser and XSDs.

Comment: All of my XML will be similar format. How can I change the code now?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Use a XML parser. It will throw an error if the XML is not well formed. If this is for learning purposes you should learn that it is a bad idea to want to parse XML with regular expressions. See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I'm not wrong this should work:

```
((<(\\S(.*?))(\\s.*?)?>(.*?)<\\/\\3>)|(<\\S(.*?)(.*?)(\\/>)))
```

I just tested it using this site: https://regex101.com/ (for further tests ;) )
and added the java escape backslashes.

I basically just escaped the forwardslash in the closingtag for regex and grouped the whole first content of the tag, so the \1 reffers to the whole thing.
If something doesnt work just let me know :)

Edit: changed it to let it check tags with arguments as well

Edit: after all the editing it got quite messy, It's probably possible to make this look better but it works this way as far as I can tell

Comment: I would like to accept the answer but , it doesn't work for me. can you test it here `http://regexr.com/` ?

Comment: It matches with the inner tags, but, I need to match the entire String

Comment: It doesnt because of the lineendings. If you remove all the \n it would work
wait a second

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought the multiline part in your code does this